# Android Kotlin BLE setValue error

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

New to Kotlin and Android.

I have a setValue that I'm doing on a characteristic that is suddenly failing.

I can not figure out how to get an error object out of it.  Is it possible that in the Android world we don't get an error reason when the write fails on a characteristic?

Anyone know how to pull an error reason out of this situation?

```
private fun writeMyCharacteristic(characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic) {
    val payload = BluetoothUtils.packagePayload()

    mClientActionListener.log(TAG_GATT_CLIENT_CALLBACK, "** Made it to writeCharacteristic")

    if (!mConnected) {
        mClientActionListener.log(TAG_GATT_CLIENT_CALLBACK, "** Failed to connect")

        return
    }

    mClientActionListener.log(TAG_GATT_CLIENT_CALLBACK, "** Writing the payload: ${payload.contentToString()}")

    characteristic.setValue(payload)

    val success = mGatt!!.writeCharacteristic(characteristic)

    if (success) {
        mClientActionListener.log(TAG_GATT_CLIENT_CALLBACK,"** Wrote: " + payload.contentToString())
    } else {

        /// Here is where I want to know WHY it was not a success.
        mClientActionListener.logError(TAG_GATT_CLIENT_CALLBACK,"** Failed to write to the characteristic.")
    }
}
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Look at your logic

Comment: @Henrique Mendes.  What were you referring to exactly.  Myself and another dev here have looked at the code and can't seen a logic error.

Comment: I do not understand why it calls the function to know if it is true or false inside itself. The variable mGatt!! ...

Comment: AH!  That was bad naming convention.  I named my function the same as a native function.  That has been changed since.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But did you look at the logcat? There you will see the error. Change the filter to "Error" (logcat).

Comment: Where does your Bluetooth characteristic come from? Is it from the Bluetooth client or from a new instantiation?

Comment: @HenriqueMendes No it doesn't show in LogCat.  It just says failed to connect.  I need to know why it failed and the setValue function knows internally but it doesn't throw it back up to he calling function.

Comment: @xiaomi BluetoothGattCharacteristic **is** the BLE peripheral.

Comment: How do you connect the Gatt ? Do you use service discovery to retrieve the list of services / characteristics included into the gatt ?

Comment: @xiaomi - no. In this case I just need to write one value to the BLE peripheral.